# Show that $ \sum_{k=1}^{p-1} (k-1)! (p-k)! k^{p-1} \equiv 0 \pmod p\ $ for odd prime $ \ p \ $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $ \ p \ $ be an odd prime number . Show that $$ \sum_{k=1}^{p-1} (k-1)! (p-k)! k^{p-1} \equiv 0 \pmod p \ $$

**Answer:**

Now,

$ \sum_{k=1}^{p-1} (k-1)! (p-k)! k^{p-1} \\ =\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} k! (p-k)! k^{p-2} \\ =\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} (-1)^k k^{p-2} \ \pmod  p \\=-1+2^{p-2}-3^{p-2}+......+(-1)^{p-1} (p-1)^{p-2} \pmod p $

But I can not conclude the result.

Help me doing this

Comment: It may help that $k^{p-2} \equiv k^{-1} \mod p$ (Fermat's little theorem)

Comment: given $ \ p \ $ is odd prime. I just forgot to mention

Comment: For composite $p>4$, all the terms in the sum are zero mod $p$. The case $p=4$ can be tested separately. This plus the proof below, and your equality is true for all $p>2$, prime or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you are using is wrong. What is true is the following $$(k-1)!(p-k)! \equiv (-1)^{k} \pmod p$$

Now using the Fermat's Little Theorem that $k^{p-1} \equiv 1\pmod p$ your have

$$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} (k-1)! (p-k)! k^{p-1} \equiv \sum_{k=1}^{p-1} (-1)^{k} \equiv 0 \pmod p$$

---

The above fact is true as $(p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod p$ by Wilson's Theorem and then $$(k-1)!(p-k)! \equiv (-1)^{k-1}(p-k+1)(p-k+2)\cdots(p-1)(p-k)! \equiv (-1)^k \pmod p$$

Comment: I need to prove without using $ \ (k-1)! (p-k_)! \equiv (-1)^k \ \ (mod \ p) \ $

Comment: @yourmath Unfortunately I can't see another way at the moment. Anyway even if you don't know it you can prove it in a couple of lines, as I did above

Comment: How the last expression $ (-1)^k (p-k+1)(p-k+2).........(p-1)(p-k)! \equiv (-1)^k \ (mod \ p) \ $ ?

Comment: It's equal to $(-1)^{k-1}(p-1)! \equiv (-1)^k \pmod p$ by Wilson's Theorem